# Tablet UI passing arguments between between 2 arguments not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am Checking if the device screen is twopane or singlepane. If twopane i want to pass arguments(Object) to another fragment in view by using bundle for it to dynamically load. if single pane i want to start a new activity by using start intent for the fragment. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a bool resource in your strings.xml file. This bool resource "is_tablet" should be set to true in sw600dp/strings.xml and false in values/strings.xml.

Hence you would know if this device is using a single pane or double pane. Now with this check you can launch a new activity or pass the data to other fragment.